# What do I need to check to ensure my laptop's HDMI out port will support an HDMI monitor?

Tags: display, hdmi

Is the presence of the HDMI port enough? My laptop has an HDMI out, and many monitors use HDMI, but is the presence of ports on both devices enough? I know I would need to install the proper drivers, but apart from that, what should I look for to ensure compatibility?

Comment: Usually the presence of a HDMI port on both is enough to know you will be able to use the monitor. If you want to do fancy things (e.g. 3D) then check the manuals.

Answer (score 1):

Display technology in both the hardware and the software has advanced enough in recent years that all you need is for the software to be able to talk to the hardware. Running a modern OS with a proper driver should suffice.